# Streaming video and private files?

Tags: files

I'm using the [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) [module](http://drupal.org/project/jplayer) with Drupal 7's built-in private files functionality and it's working nice and everything except that **private files won't stream**. They just get downloaded, which is kind of the opposite of what I want to happen. I want them to stream, not be easily downloaded in their entirety.

Comment: Can you capture request/response headers via Live HTTP Headers or something similar, and add to the question?

Comment: What info do you want from the HTTP headers? Are you looking for the HTTP headers from the unsuccessful attempt to stream from private files or the successful public streaming?

Comment: Unsuccessful attempt to stream from private files.  I suspect that the MIME type or content disposition is wrong, hence causing the browser to download.

Comment: If the content disposition is wrong, how do you fix that?

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think the private handler ever calls out to the function that does add that header.

Comment: There's a lot of info in the headers. It's not practical to post it all here. What should I look for in the headers?

Comment: If I were debugging it on my own server (and I was debugging a streaming problem this morning), I would want to see full headers for request and response.  It should only be about ~20 lines total for both, eg http://pastebin.com/swTbZhP3